# Google Places Autocomplete Dropdown Box

Tags: autocomplete

I have been looking at the autocomplete example of places.  The result only offers four or five results.  Is there a way to increase the number of results offered?

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the radius or geolocation?